# How to read contents of a file (.html, .txt etc) from within a nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I'm developing a NuGet package in .NET 6 where the package generates test reports in HTML. I have broken down my main HTML template into separate HTML files and placed them in a folder called 'Components'. Generated the package and installed it locally in another project to test it.

I tried two methods I've found online but none worked. I'm getting an error when running the code from the other project: `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\pathToMyProjectInWhichNuGetPackageIsInstalled\bin\Debug\net6.0\Components\MainBody.html'`.

The first method (available at https://chsamii.medium.com/how-to-include-files-within-a-nuget-package-272d39323d7e)

Here's my directory structure.

[image]

Here's my `MainBody.html` properties. I tried setting the `CopyToOutputDirectory` to both `Do Not Copy` and `Copy always`. None worked.

[image]

Here's my code to read the `MainBody.html`.

```
public class Reporter
{
    public void ReadFile()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(Reporter).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream? resource = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Reporter.Components.MainBody.html");

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resource!);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

This did not work.

The second method I found on StackOverflow itself, ([How to read text from an included content file in a nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713036/how-to-read-text-from-an-included-content-file-in-a-nuget-package)), did not work either and got the same error mentioned above.

Here's my NuGet project's `.csproj`

[image]

Here's the code I'm using the read the file.

```
public void ReadFile()
{
    var assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var textPath = Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, "Components", "MainBody.html");

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textPath);
    var result = sr.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I'm then just setting the project to generate a NuGet package on build and I'm building it. I'm not using any `.nuspec` file. In none of the tutorials were there any mention of configurations to put into it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the error message, if the `MainBody.html` file is placed in the specified path, can the problem be solved?

Comment: Is `MainBody` spelled correctly? As long as it’s in the path you specified (try printing the Assembly Directory) it should work correctly.